# how to backup sonarqube configurations and its data to gitlab

Tags: version-control, sonarqube, gitlab

Today I want to backup sonar, but I am not sure how to back it up to GitLab using sonar plugins or manual Please could you help me with some instructions? What do I need to backup in Sonar for configuration and its data.

Comment: This question is better suited for the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) stack.

Comment: In a production environment the data should be stored in an external database.